# Button to search for questions

Tags: support, search, tag-watching

How about a button to search for questions within interesting tags?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a good ratio of interesting:ignored in your tags lists, and you have hidden those you're ignoring, the search already works just fine for filtering through your interesting tags.

When you search, those that match your ignore+hidden list will disappear from display, leaving you with those that are on your interesting and any fluff that comes through. Most of the time the fluff is stuff that doesn't distract too much and if it does, it's just another thing to add to your ignore list.

If you want to search within a particular tag, load it up in the field with square brackets (`[]`) to make sure it's treated as a tag.

Say you want to search all questions tagged **[svn]** that contain the word "conflict":

> [**[svn]** conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvn%5D+conflict)

Comment: So if I have 6 tags that I wish to see questions for, I just have to add the other 28000 to my ignore list? :)

Comment: Also, you can combine tags as follows: [json] [python]